# What text editors operate like notepad for Windows but with extra features for a novice?

Tags: windows, text-editor

What text editors are as easy as Notepad for Windows 7, but with the extra features below?

- Advanced Find and Replace functions (replacing line endings would be helpful)
- See [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) in my text
- Add control characters to my text
- Read multiple files at the same time (tabs and side-by-side view)

I would prefer a free program, but can pay a little bit for software if it is really good, maybe USD10.

Comment: Just about any editor other than Notepad can do all this. (I'm having trouble parsing your third paragraph though.) Yes, I know you wrote “for a novice”… but that's a highly ambiguous criterion, every vi user starts out as a novice.

Answer (score 20):

Try [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). It's free, so you don't lose anything. Furthermore, it's GPL, so if you're interested, you can modify it, it if needed. I did use it before switching exclusively to Mac, and it was really nice. I don't remember hitting any issues. For programming, it offered highlighting and parsing (collapsing etc.). Your requirements:

- **Advanced Find and Replace functions (replacing line endings would be helpful)**: yes. Supports also `\n`, `\t` etc., and regular expressions for more complex patterns.
- **See control characters in my text**: yes, "View -> Show symbol -> Show all characters"
- **Add control characters to my text**: yes, at least with [hexeditor](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central) plugin (search for "hexeditor" from that page).
- **Read multiple files at the same time (tabs and side-by-side view)**: [tabs](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/assets/images/scsh/scsh_gui_tabCloseButton.png) yes, and fully customizable. I'm not sure about side-by-side view. Based on [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/215917/how-can-i-view-two-files-side-by-side-in-notepad), yes: right click on tab and select "Move to Other view".

[image: Screenshot from notepad-plus-plus.org]

It's almost as simple as basic notepad, but contains quite a bit of [features](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/):

> - Syntax Highlighting and Syntax Folding
> - User Defined Syntax Highlighting and Folding: screenshot 1, screenshot 2, screenshot 3 and -screenshot 4
> - PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expression) Search/Replace
> - GUI entirely customizable: minimalist, tab with close button, multi-line tab, vertical tab and vertical document list
> - Document Map
> - Auto-completion: Word completion, Function completion and  Function parameters hint
> - Multi-Document (Tab interface)
> - Multi-View
> - WYSIWYG (Printing)
> - Zoom in and zoom out
> - Multi-Language environment supported
> - Bookmark
> - Macro recording and playback
> - Launch with different arguments

Comment: Notepad++ also has the side-by-side view (that the OP mentions) with horizontal/vertical scroll synchronization.